# Python DEAP - Getting the Pareto Front for every generation

Tags: deap

I am using DEAP to run a multi objective optimization using `eaSimple`. The code returns the `ParetoFront()` after the last generation.
Is there any way to get a set of `ParetoFront()` for each generation? I would like to see the evolution of the fronts with every generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply run one generation at a time. Each time, run the algorithm on the population that was output by the previous run.

Something like

```py
ngen = 50
pop = toolbox.population(n=100)

for i in range(ngen):
    pop, logbook = algorithms.eaSimple(pop, toolbox, cxpb=0.5, mutpb=0.2, ngen=1)
```

You just need to add whatever you are doing with the Pareto front to the above code.